# I want an onClick button to update my state with a random object from array on every click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, setstate

So,this should be pretty simple but I'm really struggling. I want to make a quote generator.
I have an array of objects, each containing a quote and it's author.

I have a button, and each time it's clicked, I want the state to update with a randomly chosen object from the array.

Here is where I'm at, I've tried many things but nothing has worked properly.
https://codesandbox.io/s/quotebox-0iyht?file=/src/index.js

Here is the code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Myarray = [
  {
    quote: "Well, Ted, like I said the last time: 'it won't happen again'. ",
    author: "Father Dougal"
  },

  {
    quote:
      "  So there he is. Risen from the dead. Like that fella.... E.T. ",
    author: "Father Ted"
  },

  {
    quote:
      " These are small, but those are far away... Small, far away.",
    author: "Father Ted"
  },

  {
    quote:
      "Sorry Ted, I was concentrating too hard on looking holy.",
    author: "Father Dougal"
  }
];

function Quotebox() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    quote: "Well, Ted, like I said the last time: 'it won't happen again'. ",
    author: "Father Dougal"
  });

  return (
    <>
      <p>{state.quote}</p>
      <p>- {state.author}</p>

      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setState({
            quote: "want this to be a random quote from array on every click",
            author: "want this to be the author on every click"
          })
        }
      >
        {" "}
        change{" "}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quotebox />, rootElement);
```

Here is an example of what I want to make, only I don't want to fetch data from an API, I just want to get it from my array.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quote-generator-q3mlk?file=/src/components/QuotePage.jsx:319-346

There are other examples online but they all use class components. I would rather do it the "modern" way, and use a functional component with Hooks. Should I be using useEffect instead of setState? setState seems to be only capable of upating the state on the first click, but I'v seen other components online where they continuously increment/decrement the state with every click, but it never seems to work for me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: I tried simple on your sandbox. Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/quotebox-forked-1x1bj?file=/src/index.js) you want?

Comment: @Shubham, yes, that works!

Answer (score 0):

useEffect basically a trigger function to do some thing when something happen and what its triggers are it's dependencies. When some dependency on a useEffect change that useEffect function will be triggered. You shouldn't give functions to it's dependencies that doesnt return a variable because its seemles(you can check useCallback hook to do something like that). The way you doing is a modern way to do what you want to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by maintaining index of quote in state and on every click update index randomly, I've made some changes to Quotebox component

```
function Quotebox() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0); // setting 1st quote as default

  function changeQuote() {
    let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Myarray.length - 0) + 0); // now on every click setting a random index between 0 and quotes array length (quotes array length is excluded)
    setIndex(newIndex);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{Myarray[index].quote}</p>
      <p>- {Myarray[index].author}</p>

      <button onClick={changeQuote}> change </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **are** updating the state on every button click, only you are updating it with the same value over and over again!

If you want to generate a *random* quote, you have to change your `setState`  call to something like this:

```
setState(
  Myarray[parseInt(Math.random() * Myarray.length)]
)
```

You shouldn't be using `useEffect` hook in your example. That hook aims to replace class components' lifecycle methods `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`.

As a React beginner, you can safely forget about `useEffect` and focus on key concepts, such as *state*,  *props* and the flow of data from parent to child components.

Comment: @McSha8 You're welcome! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)